# Unpivoting dataframe

Tags: r, unpivot, melt

I have a data frame looking like this : data.frame name cond

```
CONDITION  CONT1 CONT2  CONT3 CONT4 
result      16.2  2.5   6.5   0.75
Test.ratio  0.23  0.15  2.5   3.5
```

What I want to do get is:

```
CONDITION Result test.ratio
CONT1      16.2  0.62 
CONT2      2.5   0.15
CONT3      6.5   2.5 
CONT4      0.75  3.5
```

I tried using the melt function but it didnt work.

```
Cond.long <- melt(cond, idvar = "condition"))
```

I'm new to R.

Comment: Using `tidyr` : `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -CONDITION) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = CONDITION, values_from = value)`

Answer (score 1):

**base**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "CONDITION  CONT1 CONT2  CONT3 CONT4 
result      16.2  2.5   6.5   0.75
Test.ratio  0.23  0.15  2.5   3.5 ", header = T)
new <- t(df[, -1]) 
colnames(new) <- df[, 1]
new
#>       result Test.ratio
#> CONT1  16.20       0.23
#> CONT2   2.50       0.15
#> CONT3   6.50       2.50
#> CONT4   0.75       3.50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Similar approach: `t("rownames<-"(as.matrix(df[, -1]), df[[1]]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('CONT')) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = CONDITION) %>% select('CONDITION' = name, 2,3)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  CONDITION result Test.ratio
  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 CONT1      16.2        0.23
2 CONT2       2.5        0.15
3 CONT3       6.5        2.5 
4 CONT4       0.75       3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option using `dcase` + `melt`

```
> dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "CONDITION"), variable ~ CONDITION)
   variable Test.ratio result
1:    CONT1       0.23  16.20
2:    CONT2       0.15   2.50
3:    CONT3       2.50   6.50
4:    CONT4       3.50   0.75
```